# Convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with 'pd.Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Getting future warning in pandas when comparing python datetime with dates in pandas.
Not sure how to do this conversion.

```
        date1 = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
        date2 = datetime.date(year, month, days)
        dd = df.loc[df['Date'].between(date1, date2), ['Col1','Col2', 'Col3','Col4','Col5']]
        r = rowpos[month]
```

> ```
> /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:3658:
> ```
>
> FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'. 
>   Currently, the 'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future
>   pandas will not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To retain the
>   current behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with
>   'pd.Timestamp'.   lmask = self >= left

Comment: Have you tried, as suggested, `pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(year, month, 1))` ?

Comment: That worked excellent. If i wanted to create a timestamp for today, do i need to do it with datetime and then convert? like "today = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today())" or can i create it directly with pandas?

Comment: Just use `pd.Timestamp('today')` or, if you want to zero out time, `pd.Timestamp('today').normalize()`.